# apply first of a list of functions in Clojure

Tags: syntax, clojure

if i have a list of functions:

`(def lst '(+ -))`

and i wish to apply the first of that list (+) to a list of numbers, i would think its

`(apply (first lst) '(1 2 3 4))`

but apparently U am wrong? Syntax mistake I assume. How do I do this?

PS:

```
=>(first lst)  
+

=>(apply (first lst) '(1 2 3 4))   
4
```

both return without error, they just return what i WOULD expect in the first case, and what i would NOT expect in the second.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since your list is quoted:

```
(def lst '(+ -))
       ; ^- quote!
```

its members are two *symbols*, not functions. A symbol in Clojure can be used as a function, but then it acts very much like a keyword (i.e. looks itself up in its argument):

```
('foo {'foo 1})
; => 1
```

The correct solution is to use a list -- or, more idiomatically, a vector -- of functions:

```
(def lst (list + -)) ; ok
; or...
(def lst `(~+ ~-))   ; very unusual in Clojure
; or...
(def lst [+ -])      ; the idiomatic solution
```

Then your `apply` example will work.

By the way, notice that a function, when printed back by the REPL, doesn't look like the symbol which names it:

```
user=> +
#<core$_PLUS_ clojure.core$_PLUS_@10c10de0>
```

Comment: ahhhhhh. that makes so much sense now. just had to hear it from somebody that knew what they were doing. thanks a lot.